# pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: 'writeStream' can be called only on streaming Dataset/DataFram

Tags: pyspark, amazon-kinesis, apache-hudi, glue-streaming

I am having glue streaming job, and I need to write the data as stream but after applying some processing, so I did the following:

```
data_frame_DataSource0 = glueContext.create_data_frame.from_catalog(
    database=database_name,
    table_name=kinesis_table_name,
    transformation_ctx="DataSource0",
    additional_options={"inferSchema": "true", "startingPosition": starting_position_of_kinesis_iterator}
)
glueContext.forEachBatch(
    frame=data_frame_DataSource0,
    batch_function=processBatch,
    options={
        "windowSize": window_size,
        "checkpointLocation": s3_path_spark
    }
)
```

and in `processBatch` I do some processing and at the end of it i do the following:

```
  df.writeStream.format("hudi").options(**combinedConf).outputMode('append').start()
```

I am getting the following error:

```
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: 'writeStream' can be called only on streaming Dataset/DataFram
```

as far as I unserstand that the df I am trying to write is not streaming that's why it's giving the error, I am not so aware how can I change it from the glue context and how I can apply the processing on the streaming data then writeStream it?

any idea please?

Answer (score 0):

`forEachBatch` method processes streaming Dataset/DataFrame on batches of Dataset/DataFrame, so when we call it on `data_frame_DataSource0`, the `df` passed to the method `processBatch` is a normal Dataset/DataFrame contains a batch of data.

You have two options to fix this:

1. deal with the df as normal dataframe:

   ```py
   df.write.format("hudi").options(**combinedConf).mode("append").save()
   ```
2. apply your stream processing directly on `data_frame_DataSource0`:

   ```py
   data_frame_DataSource0 = glueContext.create_data_frame.from_catalog(
       database=database_name,
       table_name=kinesis_table_name,
       transformation_ctx="DataSource0",
       additional_options={"inferSchema": "true", "startingPosition": starting_position_of_kinesis_iterator}
   )
   (
       data_frame_DataSource0.writeStream.format("hudi")
       .options(**combinedConf)
       .option("inferSchema", "true")
       .option("startingPosition", starting_position_of_kinesis_iterator)
       .outputMode('append').start()
   )
   ```